# Integrate ReportPortal with TestComplete

Tags: testcomplete, reportportal, postman-newman

I am doing a feasibility study to integrate ReportPortal with TestComplete for our project, Currently trying to hit the API call available in this 'http://{IP Address}:8080/ui/#api' using aqhttp, still exploring on that, So would I like to know is my current approach is possible and is there any best way to do this for TestComplete.

TestComplete doesnot provide any special integration with ReportPortal,

So I am Currently checking if I can hit the Reportportal API call available in this 'http://{IP Address}:8080/ui/#api' using postman, But I mostly getting HTML response, And I don't know most of the parameter usages available there.

Thanks you,

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint you mentioned points to Swagger UI, so use browser to see API documentation.
Base URLs for ReportPortal APIs are:

- `http://{IP Address}:{PORT}/api/v1` for API service
- `http://{IP Address}:{PORT}/uat` for Authorization service (you won't need this one for your integration)